# write() doesn't write the data

Tags: c, unix, io

I want to copy file1 content to file2, but after the write command file2 is still empty.

```
int fd1;
int fd2;
size_t len;
size_t nbytes;
ssize_t bytes_read;

fd1 = open(file1, O_RDWR);

fd2 = open(file2, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 );
char *buf[len];

nbytes = sizeof(buf);
bytes_read = read(fd1, buf, nbytes);

write(fd2, &bytes_read, nbytes); 

close(fd1);
close(fd2);

return 0;
```

Is there something bad with this line?

```
char *buf[len];
```

Should I use malloc or memset instead?

Comment: _Is there something bad with this line? char *buf[len];_ yes, you want a string (an array of chars) not an array of pointers to chars, change to `char buf[len];`, and you are using `len` uninitialized.

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` is compile time, `buf` initialization is not.

Comment: Well first len is undefined. Also, by using char *buf[len] you create a "2D" array [Or at least a pointer on an array]

Comment: @tilz0R For VLA:s, `sizeof` is determined at runtime.

Comment: @kaldoran, The OP has an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. A pointer to an array looks like `Type (*aptr)[dim];`

Comment: Basically change `char *buf[len];` to `char buf[1000];`. And check the return values of `open`. You can remove `size_t len;`, it's no longer needed.

Comment: this line: `fd1 = open( argv[1], O_RDWR)`  is not correct as the code is not writing to the input file.  suggest: `fd1 = open( argv[1], O_RDONLY)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int fd1, fd2;
  size_t len, nbytes;
  ssize_t bytes_read;
  struct stat st;

  fd1 = open("./file1.txt", O_RDWR);

  if ((fd1 != -1) &&(fstat(fd1, &st) == 0)) {
        len = st.st_size;
      }

  fd2 = open("./file2.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 );

  char buf[len];
  nbytes = sizeof(buf);

  if((fd1 != -1) && (fd2 != -1)){
    bytes_read = read(fd1, buf, nbytes);
    write(fd2, buf, nbytes);
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
  }else {
    printf("error \n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

You should change the buf from `char *buf[len]` to `char buf[len]` and to get the length of file1 you can use these instructions:

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
len = ftell(fp);
```

Before using buf, try to use `memset`.

Comment: Please explain: 'bytes_read = read(fd1, buf, nbytes);  write(fd2, buf, nbytes);'   Why are you not writing the number of bytes read?

Comment: this answer is failing to check for errors!  Assuming that every system call is successful is a very bad programming practice.

Comment: with a 'large' file, placing the array `char buf[len] on the stack will create a program crash due to stack overflow. IF wanting to copy the whole file, read a reasonable amount, write the amount read in a loop until `read()` returns 0

Comment: `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);` on a binary stream is not strictly-conforming C code.  Binary streams have no requirement to support `fseek(..., SEEK_END );`  In fact, [it's explicitly undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268): *Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream ...*

Comment: @ThingyWotsit *What is the memset() for? It's a pointless waste of cycles.*  Not necessarily (though it probably is in this case).  Imagine a truly high-speed disk system that can deliver data much faster than the host can map pages into the process' address space.  Yeah, I've worked on those types of systems - a `memset()` like that ensures that the physical memory used to receive the data actually is both available and is mapped into the address space before trying to fill it with data coming in at a few GB per second.  Note that `calloc()` may not actually work...

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't understand your comment about `fseek`

Comment: @HmidiSlim Using `fseek()` to find the size of a binary file is, per the C Standard, undefined behavior.  I have no idea why it's taught so widely without that warning.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So what have I use to get the size? Should I use `stat`function instead?

Comment: @HmidiSlim Since your code is already using POSIX `open()`, `read()`, and `write()`, using POSIX `stat()` would be appropriate.  Or even `fstat()` on the file descriptor on the file being read.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I edited the answer.You can check it now.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. checks for and handles errors
3. corrects the problems listed in the comments to the question
4. Note: this assumes file names are from command line arguments

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>   // perror(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#include <sys/types.h>  // open()
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>     // write(), close(), read()

#define MAX_BUF_LEN 1024

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int fd1;
    int fd2;

    ssize_t bytes_read;

    if( 3 != argc )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFileName outputFileName\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( 0 > (fd1 = open( argv[1], O_RDONLY)) )
    {
        perror( "open for input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    if( 0 > (fd2 = open( argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 )) )
    {
        perror( "open for output file failed" );
        close( fd1 );  // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    char buf[ MAX_BUF_LEN ];


    while( (bytes_read = read( fd1, buf, MAX_BUF_LEN )) )
    {
        if( 0 > bytes_read )
        { // then read error event
            perror( "read failed" );
            break;  // exit while() loop
        }

        else
        {
            // EDIT: following line incorrect.
            //ssize_t bytes_written = write( fd2, &bytes_read, (size_t)bytes_read );
            // corrected line:
            ssize_t bytes_written = write( fd2, buf, (size_t)bytes_read );

            if( bytes_read != bytes_written )
            { // then write error event
                fprintf( stderr, "bytes read: %ld, bytes written: %ld\n", bytes_read, bytes_written );
                break; // exit while() loop
            }
        }
    } // end while()

    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: There is some problem with your code.I tried to put one word in the input file but I don't get it in the output file.When I put a sentence in the inputFile I got some garbage before the sentence in the outputFile.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake.  The `write()` statement was starting at the address of the variable `bytes_read` rather than at the address of `buf[]`.  Thanks for catching that.